# select field from one table and match it in another table and return vales

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables

**categories**

```
categories (cid, year_id, category_title)
```

**users**

```
users (uid, year_id, name, rollno, password)
```

when user login with his rollno and password i want to show his category by 
selecting `year_id` from 'user' and matching for that `year_id` in 'categories'

i'm trying

SELECT * FROM categories WHERE (select year_id='$year' from users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple join

```
SELECT c.* FROM categories c
JOIN users u ON(c.year_id =u.year_id)
WHERE u.year_id='$year'
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT c.*,u.year_id user_year FROM categories c
JOIN users u ON(c.year_id =u.year_id)
WHERE  u.uid='$user_id'
```

Comment: one more problem here is how to grab year_id of logged in user from users table

Comment: If `$user_id` is in fact the value that you are basing your search on, then a JOIN would be prescribed here and this answer would work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help MKhalidJunaid and Benjam..

Answer (score 0):

If the `year_id` is the same for both, and you know the `year_id` that was returned from the `users` table, just use that value in a select on the `categories` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM `categories`
WHERE `year_id` = '[year_id from users data]'
```

No join needed.

**UPDATE:**

To validate the user login:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `rollno` = '[users rollno]'
```

Then compare the password returned from that query to the password provided by the user, and if they match, you know the user is valid, and can use the `year_id` that was also returned to grab the categories.

Comment: one more problem here is how to grab year_id of logged in user from users table

Comment: See updated answer. Also... your original question is not very clear on what you are asking/needing.